# How can i use onClick event in styled component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have a problem with styled. I will write my problem with images. I have a image button and if i click on image button, the MenuItemContainer must be visibility.

```css
const MenuItemContainer = styled.div`
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  border: 1px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.lightBlueGrey};
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 24px 0px ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.dark15};
`;

const ProfileNameWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 25px;
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.darkGreyBlue};
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  &:hover ${TooltipText} {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  &:????? ${MenuItemContainer} {
    visibility: visible;
  }
`;
```

can i use onClick here?

```css
 &:????? ${MenuItemContainer} {
    visibility: visible;
  }
```

Comment: Please never post code in as an image. Instead use a "stack snippet". Make sure it is a [mcve].

Comment: Text embedded in images is unsearchable. This is a community site, and we hope that questions and answers will be useful to other users. They'll have trouble finding a question that has valuable info locked up in images. Please correct this.

Comment: Also may you please show where you're using the `onclick`?

Comment: try `&:active` or `&:target` but this is not the right way to do what you want. I think there is a better approach using a hidden checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Even though, I find it wrong to attach click events on divs, you can utilize the aria attributes to hack your way around your problem.

```
const ProfileNameWrapper = styled.div`
  ...
  &:[aria-expanded='true'] ${MenuItemContainer} {
    visibility: visible;
  }
`

const Component: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false)
  return (
     <ProfileNameWrapper onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)} aria-expanded={expanded} />
  )
}
```